# Can we detect if android app is updated from google play on introduction of a new version?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-event

I have a app on play store and i want to provide app update through the play store.

Also, on updation of the app i want to perform some task. So, how can i perform a task on updation of my app from the play store.

I thought of maintaining `current version` and cross check it every time the app is fired, is there any other efficient way such as any **intent** fired on **app updation** that can be handled on the `device` itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save your current version code in shared preferences and on upgrade, cross check the new version with the previously stored one.

```
if (savedVersionCode < currentVersionCode) {
    .
    .
    //PERFORM CERTAIN TASKS...
    .
    .
}
```

You can do this in your application's `onCreate()` or simply in you launcher activity's `onCreate()` if you have only one entry point.

Answer (score 1):

The current version idea is a solid one. Just store it in the shared preferences and read it from there. It isn't really slow so the "negative" impact on performance can be simply ignored.

Comment: is there any intent that can be handled if the app itself is updated?

Comment: there are some `PACKAGE_*` intents but if I remember correctly there is no guarantee that your receiver will be registered before this one will be fired. So again: the current version comparison is the way to go...